# Change the location of the .install4j folder

Tags: install4j

In the files step, I created a root folder where I would install the distributed files, however the .install4j folder still gets generated inside `C:\Program Files`.
I want to know, how I could change its location for example to the custom root folder I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .install4j folder is always created in the installation directory. You cannot move it to a different installation root.

Comment: In fact, what I needed is to change the installation folder somewhere else than Program Files, I found that option in Media's Installer options.